# Kendo UI - sorting grid by date with null values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

for my project I need to sort the contents of a KendoUI Grid by a Date column, where nulls are allowed.

Currently I use something like this:

```
var grid = $('#MyGrid').data('kendoGrid');
grid.dataSource.sort({ field: 'DateColumnName', dir: 'asc' });
```

Problem is that I need the rows having the `DateColumnName` property `null` appear after those that have some value (not before, like they do now).

I found some solutions using some undocummented `grid.sortable.compare` property, but I create the grid in MVC and can't access the mentioned property after the grid has been created.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to access `grid.sortable.compare` after the grid has been created and not when it is created? Why do you say that `grid.sortable.compare` is undocumented? Is [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.sortable.compare) not what you are looking for?

Comment: @OnaBai thanks for the link, so the function is docummented after all :) The reason I need to access it later is that I create the grid in MVC.NET, and it doesn't have API for acces to the `compare` property.